# CfWheels: Subqueries Solution

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion, cfwheels

I am using CFWheels and trying to find a way to do subqueries. I want to know what options are available. Currently I am constructing my queries using plain old Coldfusion query and adding a huge string of the query in execution. I want to know if there are more cleaner options available using CFWheels model functionality.

My table is:

[image]

I wish to perform this query on the table:

```
select COUNT(tb1.formid) as number_of_submission, tb1.formid
from ( select formid, room, inspector
from test_tbl
group by formid, room, inspector) tb1
group by tb1.formid;
```

Which displays the following:

[image]

And just to elaborate a bit more, the inner query gives:

[image]

Comment: Would `select formid, count(distinct formid) number_of_submissions from test_tbl group by formid` not give you the information you need?

Comment: no it didn't work, mainly because if you group  by formid, then there are only 2 form id there, what distinguishes each submission is a unique set of unique formid, room, and inspector.

Answer (score 0):

There is the grouping function available for models that looks something like this:

```
counts=model("test_tbl").findAll( 
     select="tb1.formid, COUNT(tb1.formid) AS publishCount"
    , group="formid, room, inspector"
);
```

but unless you can find a way to do a single group to get the result, you won't be able to use the model this way.

There are some other options too though, which might be viewed as less favorable.

**use a (db) view**
- I've got several views going that have a this kind of grouping, and I use the models for read-only interaction on these. The downside is that some of the logic is in the views, and making changes is a little more cumbersome as a result.

**use select, but as a function inside the model**
- add your select function inside the model and make it available through a function. When you want to access this kind of grouping or count, you would call the model like so `test_tbl.getSubmissions()`. This way your select code is in the model where it IMO should be as opposed to a controller.

Anecdotally... a while back I've gone through a bunch of models and replaced the complex multi table relationships with `select` for a significant performance boost. So using select is not necessarily a bad thing.